# Linking Images to Data - Answered

Tags: image

[Question Answered by Mark Setchell]

I don't actually code; so this is going to be a tough one for you guys. 
I'm developing a 2D Indie Game that uses Java and C# running on DirectX/Direct3. I'm lead (first) Designer. So, it's my task to get all of the Files ready for the Test Phase so that I can show them to Coders so that they can make it work as a Game. (So far, I've made all of the Images; so I'm ready to begin creating my File Structure)

So here's where I'm getting stuck. I need to find a way to link multiple Images together (for animations), and with each Image having its' own Variables associated to determine Animation Delay, Image Off-Set Position, Z Layer to choose which Images are supposed to be in-front of one another (Like; if they were Windows in the UI and one was a Pop-Up Window after Clicking on a Button or something to that effect); item names, things like that.

So what I'm wondering is one of these things:
- if anyone knows a Program that is actually capable of me doing the Linking of Images together and attaching my own Variables before exporting as some random file type that I'm unaware of, to be used by the Coders later once all of my files are ready.
- if anyone is capable of writing me a beginner's how-to on how I would be capable of doing this given my lack of coding knowledge.

If accomplishing the above is impossible, does anyone know what I should be aiming for in terms of my File Structure before sending it to the Coders?

Originally, I was aiming for .IMG Files to do this kind of thing, but I found a very lack of guides on how .IMG Files can be created to accomplish this; most Guides or Programs were trying to convince me to make a Disc, but I just wanted to use the .IMG Files as my way of Linking the Images together with the Data Variables all the while still containing a Folder-Mechanism. So, I'm open to alternate File Options.

Note that I dont need to get ALL Variables for the Game in these Files, I really only need what I mentioned, as the rest will be Client Sided. 
Thank you for any time and effort you put into aiding me~

**Responses to Comments:**

1. Response to ivanivan:
   Good idea, I definitely will be asking them what they think would be best.
2. Response to MarkSetchell (1/3):
   That's an amazing idea, but i feel like it might wind up becoming confusing for organization with having all my pictures being titled IDs. If I were to do this, do you think it would be possible to have an actual Picture Name after the encoded filename? Like maybe if it were s43f82z2x600y300_Unit001_Attack_43.png instead; do you think that would complicate anything?
3. Response to MarkSetchell (2&3/3):
   Okay, I dont really understand those two parts, so I'm going to have to wait until after I've quoted you to the Coders

Comment: This is more project management than coding, but I would start by asking one of the developers, perhaps your counterpart on the coding side (lead dev, etc)

Comment: Why not encode it in the filename? So scene 43, frame 82, with Z position 2 and X offset 600 and Y offset 300 gets filename `s43f82z2x600y300.gif`

Comment: Or, if that doesn't work for you, use `jhead` or `exiftool` to embed that information in the image metadata, say in the *comment* section.

Comment: Or, if that doesn't work for you, generate unique filenames with `uuidgen` and use a CSV file, or sqlite database, to attach the `uuid` to a soecific scene, frame and Z index.

Answer (score 0):

*I apologize if this is the wrong way to close my Question, but I haven't been able to figure out how to mark your Comment as the Answer*

**Answer from @Mark Setchell**

"Why not encode it in the filename? So scene 43, frame 82, with Z position 2 and X offset 600 and Y offset 300 gets filename s43f82z2x600y300.gif"

**My Solution:**

I talked with one of the Coders and he said it would be fine to use any of those Solutions; I'm going to use that Response's method in the meantime while also including the file name with the underscores at the end, while he actually builds a simple program from scratch to allow me to do this. Thank you for all of your help, much appreciated ^~^